# I want to revert changes I made to a page

Tags: kentico

I made a change to a widget on a page, and saved it.  Now I want to revert back to the previous version of that widget.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you have workflow or versioning enabled you could rollback using the Versions tab under properties of a page.

If you have not, or the version is no longer available the only thing would be looking into a Database backup.